# c# ObservableCollection NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs Members

Tags: events, collections, observablecollection, eventargs

Why the class `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` in the `ObservableCollection`'s event `CollectionChanged` have the properties:

```
IList NewItems
IList OldItems
```

As `IList` (notice the s at the end, also when I use it I have to call it like `NewItems[0]`) if the `ObservableCollection` don't allow Add Range, what is the purpose of that if the item modified will always be 1 item ? Or I am missing something ?